# Regex pattern to match ticker symbol

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match ticker symbols that have the following format:

**Part1:** A market identifier code (MIC) which is used to specify exchange on which the securities are traded. The code is unique, includes four characters, and starts with X, followed by a three-digit code to signify the market, such as XNAS for the Nasdaq market.

Part1 is separated from Part2 by a colon.

**Part2:** A ticker code which has two parts:
(a) The security code which is typically anything from 1 char (F for Ford), to 5 chars (VFIAX for the Vanguard 500 Index). Th
(b) An optional part which can be further split into
(i)   Expiration date, 6 digits in the format yymmdd
(ii)  Option type, either P or C, for put or call
(iii) Strike price, as the price x 1000, front padded with 0s to 8 digits

A gotcha that I need to handle is that when the optional part is present (**sometimes**) the security code is padded with spaces to 6 characters.

So I need to match the following valid tickers:

```
XLON:SBRY
XNAS:TSLA
XCME:SPX   141122P00019500
XNAS:AAPL200918C00032500
```

My regexfu is not great, and this is what I've managed to come up with so far:

`^(X)(A-Z){3}(:)(\d|[A-Z]){1,6}\s`

What is the correct regex that matches all of the above valid ticker symbols and matches the parts correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the matches using:

```
^X[A-Z]{3}:[A-Z]{1,5}(?:\s*\d{6}[PC]\d{8})?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lrQN3V/1)

A bit more precise match for the month/day and the security code  padded with spaces to 6 characters could be:

```
^X[A-Z]{3}:[A-Z]{1,5}(?: {0,6}\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[012])(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[PC]\d{8})?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `X[A-Z]{3}:` Match X, 3 chars A-Z and `:`
- `[A-Z]{1,5}` Match 1-5 times A-Z
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `{0,6}\d{2}` Match 0-6 spaces and 2 digits
  - `(?:0[1-9]|1[012])` Match a month part 01 - 12
  - `(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` Match a day part 01 - 31
  - `[PC]\d{8}` Match `P` or `C` and 8 digits
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/36YHSH/1)